# How to know an equilateral hyperbola equation has or don't has integer solution?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

This is the equation

$$y=(K-3x)/(1+2x)$$

$K$ is a positive integer

I want to know for any given $K>0$, without plotting a graph, is it possible to know this equation has positive integer solutions or not?

It may be simple but I already left school for decades. I just come across maths problem again and I find it interesting. So please help.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, miss the divide sign, not multiply. It is (K-3x)/(1+2x)

Comment: Sorry, but here is no reason to call "equilateral" the hyperbola with this equation. In the old times, this type of equation was called "homographical".

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is a positive integer solution, that is, for some positive integers $x,y$:

$$K - 3x = y(1+2x)$$

Observe that:
$$2K + 3 = (2K-6x)+(3+6x) = (2y+3)(1+2x)$$

which is also a multiple of $1+2x$.

So we only need to check whether $2K+3$ has factors of the form $1+2x$.

But $2K+3$ is odd, so all its factors are odd.

However we require $x, y > 0$. This leads to (edited):
$$x< \frac K3 \implies 3 \le 1+2x < 1+\frac {2K}3 = \frac {2K+3}3$$

and we can show that, whenever $2K+3$ is not prime and greater than $9$, there is an odd factor of $2K+3$ satisfying the above inequality.

Therefore there is a positive integer solution whenever $2K+3$ is composite and $>9$.

Comment: And there are exactly ((number of factors of $2K+3$) - $2$) positive integer solutions.

Comment: What about $K=3$?
$2K+3$ is composite but there's not positive integer solutions for the equation.

Comment: Ah I see. I messed up the inequality. Except $K = 3$ then.

Comment: Then there should be exactly ((number of factors of $2K+3$)$-[3\mid K]-2$) positive integer solutions.

Comment: Thanks, but then it brings out another question. If K is a very very very large number, how can I know 2K+3 is prime or composite?

Comment: @Adam It is indeed very hard to do so, if $K$ is not divisible by $3$. Besides, there are infinitely many primes of this form (see [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)), which doesn't help.

Comment: @Adam  we get lots of questions from people whose real interest is RSA factoring or similar. The truth is that you cannot do this if you cannot correctly factor $2K+3.$ The simple reason is that any integer pair $(x,y)$ PRODUCES two nontrivial factors of $2K+3.$

Answer (score 2):

$$ (2x+1)(2y+3)  = 4xy + 6x + 2y + 3  $$

You have
$$  4xy + 6x + 2y = 2K  $$

$$ (2x+1)(2y+3)  =  3 + 2 K  $$

The integer solutions come from factoring $3+2K,$  making a list of all divisors (positive and negative), assigning one divisor to $(2x+1)$ and the appropriate quotient to $(2y+3)$

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but then it brings out another question. If K is a very very very large number, how can I factoring 3+2K?

Comment: @Adam  we get lots of questions from people whose real interest is RSA factoring or similar. The truth is that you cannot do this if you cannot correctly factor $2K+3.$ The simple reason is that any integer pair $(x,y)$ PRODUCES two nontrivial factors of $2K+3.$

Comment: Can I say in the opposite way? If K-3x=y(1+2x), then 2K+3=(1+2x)(3+2y) is a composite number. If K-3x is not divisible by 1+2x, Then P=2K+3 is a prime number? Then I can use this equation to find prime number? I believe there are database for all integers up to million digits either odd or even and which can be divided by what prime numbers are already known. Is it?